# $W_0^{1,1}([0,+\infty)) \subset L^\infty((0,\infty))$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

If we define
\begin{align*}
W^{1,1}_0 (0, \infty) = \{ f \in W^{1,1}(0, \infty):\, f(0)=0\} \ ,
\end{align*}
we can say that if $f \in W^{1,1}_0 (0, \infty) \implies f \in L^\infty (0,\infty)$?
Do you know a counterexample? Thanks for your help

Comment: Functions in $W^{1,1}([0, \infty))$ that are equal almost everywhere are identified, so it doesn't make sense to say $f(0)=0$. Is this meant in the trace-sense?

Comment: But $W^{1,1}((0,\infty))$ and $f(0)=0$ has sense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $u \in C^\infty_0((0,\infty))$. For $0<x\leqslant y$, the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus implies that \begin{align*}
\vert u(y) - u(x) \vert &= \bigg \vert \int_x^y u'(t) \, d t \bigg \vert \\
&\leqslant \int_x^y \vert u'(t) \vert  \, d t \\
&\leqslant \| u' \|_{L^1((0,\infty))}. 
\end{align*} Sending $x \to 0^+$, implies that $$ \| u \|_{L^\infty((0,\infty))} \leqslant  \| u' \|_{L^1((0,\infty))}. $$

By density of $C^\infty_0((0,\infty))$ in $W^{1,1}_0((0,\infty))$ the above inequality holds in $W^{1,1}_0((0,\infty))$.